# My CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is not applying

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a server which authenticates user with spring security filter. Client sending their login credentials in json format for validity. So i created my custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter and declared it inside http tag.

Login page is already their at client application. All that client needs to do is to create http post request with user given credentials in its request packet and send it to server for validity. Server will reply "valid"/"invalid".

**spring-security.xml:**

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
    entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

    <custom-filter ref="CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER " />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/resources/accessDenied" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/entryPoint" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    class="com.controller.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        ref="successHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
        ref="failureHandler" />
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="j_username" />
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="j_password" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="pra" password="321" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="successHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/resources/login" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="failureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/resources/accessDenied" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/resources/entryPoint" />
</beans:bean>
```

**mvc controller:**

```
@Controller
```

public class HookUpController {

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST )
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
private String homePage(){

    return "Home Page";
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/resources/entryPoint", method = RequestMethod.GET )
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
private String entryPoint(){

    return "EntryPoint";
}

@RequestMapping( value = "/resources/accessDenied", method = RequestMethod.POST )
@ResponseBody
private String accessDenied(){      
    return "invalid";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/resources/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
private String login() {
    return "valid";
}
```

}

**Issue:**

My client wants to call directly `url/resources/login` with post request containing login credentials. But control is always going into `entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"` and returning "EntryPoint" string as i have given in controller. I want to apply custom filter directly without invoking "entry-point-ref".

I think this is best i can explain about my problem. If any doubt in problem statement please do ask. And please reply solution. I have not included CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was silly mistake. Problem was with url `url/resources/login` that I was posting to authenticate the resource. It should be `url/j_spring_security_check`. As filterProcessUrl set inside UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is `<beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />`. 
Anything other than this URL will reflect to entry-point-ref tag.

My client is android app, posting request with HttpUrlConnection. HttpUrlConnection is creating post request with my data and i have not specified form submit action. After reading few posts and one that Paul John shared, this line:-`<form name='loginForm' action="j_spring_security_check"
  method='POST'>` is actually invoking security filter. Anyway problem resolved. Happens with beginners :)

Answer (score 0):

The loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint sends the user to /resources/entrypoint (as in your bean definition).

/resources/entrypoint is mapped to be allowed to all

```
<intercept-url pattern="/resources/entryPoint" access="permitAll" />
```

This is the reason the request is going to the entrypoint url - /resources/entrypoint which in turn in your controller is mapepd to return the string "EntryPoint"

Here's a good spring security tutorial - http://javakart.blogspot.ae/2012/12/spring-security-tutorial-form-login-example.html

Comment: That didn't work. But i got my problem resolved. I will post it in answer. Thanks for your tutorial link.